# Endless Loop Of Update? Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Even if i have inserted it inside an if statement with a var that contains zero value (if the qty/sku_stock is already equal), mysql still treat/sees it as an endless loop giving me an error of:

> Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

//CODE BELOW

```
DELIMITER &&
create trigger after_update_db2_t1 
after update on sample_db_two.product_inventory_tb for each row 
begin 

set @qty_col_ctr = 0;

if(new.qty != old.qty)
then
    set @qty_col_ctr := 1;
end if;

if(@qty_col_ctr = 1)
then

    update sample_db_one.products_sizes_tb set sku_stock = new.qty where sku_code=@sku_no;

end if;

END&&
DELIMITER ;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

DELIMITER &&
create trigger after_update_db1_t1 
after update on sample_db_one.products_sizes_tb for each row 
begin 

set @qty_col_ctr = 0;

if(new.sku_stock != old.sku_stock)
then
    set @qty_col_ctr := 1;
end if;


if(@qty_col_ctr = 1)
then

    update sample_db_two.product_inventory_tb set qty = new.sku_stock

end if;


END&&
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MYSQL will not allow this. If you tell us what you are trying to achieve someone may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: okay what i want to do is after my first trigger executes, i will check if the qty is changed, if it is changed then i will set a variable equal to 1, which then if my var is equal to 1 i will execute an update query that will execute another trigger which then will update qty again because they share the same qty count. but if they are already equal(old and new) then my if statement wont allow it to update the table i first describe here. please see my code above to see i what im trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The second trigger appears to be redundant unless what you want to do is to sync the 2 tables when there is an update to either one of them. In which case you may need multi-table updates instead of triggers for example.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T1,t2;

create table t1(sku int,stock int);
create table t2(sku int,qty int);

insert into t1 values(1,10),(2,10);
insert into t2 values(1,10),(2,10);

update t2 join t1 on t1.sku = t2.sku
set t2.qty = 5,
     t1.stock = case when t2.qty <> 5 then 5 end
where t2.sku = 1;

update t1 join t2 on t1.sku = t2.sku
set t1.stock = 5,
     t2.qty = case when t1.stock <> 5 then 5 end
where t1.sku = 2;

select * from t1 join t2 on t2.sku = t1.sku;    

+------+-------+------+------+
| sku  | stock | sku  | qty  |
+------+-------+------+------+
|    1 |     5 |    1 |    5 |
|    2 |     5 |    2 |    5 |
+------+-------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```